# Can I extend this partition?

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition, windows-cluster, diskmanagement

This server is running Windows Server 2008.  The drive is currently part of a Windows Cluster, so I haven't been able to extend it while the cluster is running.

I'm going to take a maintenance outage next week to break the cluster and try to extend the disk.  Will I be able to extend partition F:, since there is another partition after it?

[image: screenshot of Disk Management MMC]

If the answer is no, are there any other options to use the 85G of unallocated space?  At the very least, I should be able to create a new  85G partition, copy the data, and change the drive letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, You will not be able to expand the F: partition, and YES you can format the remaining 85GB and use it.  Drive letters can be moved around if you wish but beware as some installed programs might fail based on how you configured them.